# How to match hyphen delimited in any order

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to match a set of characters delimited by a hyphen - for example:

```
B-B/w-W/Br-W-Br
```

Where the / are part of what I need, up to 20 spaces.

```
G-R-B, G/R-B-B/W-O
```

So I need a regex that covers between the -'s in any order (G-R-B could also be R-B-G)
I've been playing around with a bunch of combo's, but I can't come up with something that will match any order.

The plan is to search this way using mysql. So, it'll be something like

```
select * from table1 where pinout REGEXP '';
```

I just can't get the regex right :/

Comment: How about `[RGB]-[RGB]-[RGB]`? (This can be written more compactly but I think this gets the point across best)

Comment: For clarity sake, could you add a complete example of the target string and the desired matching substrings?

Comment: B-B/w-W/Br-W-Br is an actual string that will be searched. this will vary from 1-15 colors - where B = Black, B/W = Black with White and so on. The idea is to search wiring diagram data but I want to avoid having to search in a very specific order. Does that answer your question?

Comment: What do you want to extract from the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

This expression will match the string providing each of the hyphen delimited values are included in the string. The color values can appear in the string in any order so this expression will match `W/Br-b-B/w` and `B/w-W/Br-b`... or any other combinations which include those colors.

```
^                 # match the start to of the string
(?=.*?(?:^|-)W\/Br(?=-|$))    # require the string to have a w/br
(?=.*?(?:^|-)b(?=-|$))        # require the string to have a b
(?=.*?(?:^|-)B\/w(?=-|$))     # require the string to have a b/w
.*                # match the entire string
```

[image]

MySql doesn't really support the look arounds so this will need to be broken into a group of where statements

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM dog WHERE ( color REGEXP '.*(^|-)W\/Br(-|$)' and color REGEXP '.*(^|-)b(-|$)' and color REGEXP '.*(^|-)B\/w(-|$)' );

+-------+--------+---------+------+------------+---------------------+
| name  | owner  | species | sex  | birth      | color               |
+-------+--------+---------+------+------------+---------------------+
| Claws | Gwen   | cat     | m    | 1994-03-17 | B-B/w-W/Br-W-Br     |
| Buffy | Harold | dog     | f    | 1989-05-13 | G-R-B, G/R-B-B/W-O  |
+-------+--------+---------+------+------------+---------------------+
```

See also this working sqlfiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/943af/1/0

Using a regex in conjunction with a MySql where statement can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: lol, wiring diagrams for cats and dogs. I like it. +1 for awesomeness. (also because you've got mad regex skills)

Comment: I follow the logic here - but not quite working in practice.


`mysql> SELECT * FROM part_conn WHERE wire_colors REGEXP '^(?=.*?(?:^|-)W\/Br(?=-|$))(?=.*?(?:^|-)b(?=-|$))(?=.*?(?:^|-)B\/w(?=-|$)).*';
ERROR 1139 (42000): Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp`


So I suspect \+ is getting seen as repetition-operator. Not sure how to get around that.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot that mysql doesn't support lookarounds. Instead it would need to be a set of `where` clauses. I updated the answer and provided a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/943af/1/0

Comment: Fantastic - thank you. Now I need to get this php form working with it. :D

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood from your example, try this:

```
-*([a-zA-Z/]+)-*
```

The capture region can be altered to include your specific letters of interest, e.g. [GRBWOgrbwo/].

Edit: I don't think this will help you in the context you're using it, but I'll leave it here for posterity.